# Handling JSONP response in Angular JS 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api, jsonp

how can i handle a jsonp response? i tried to search but i cant solve it. the screen shot below shows a jsonp result.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9aGf.png)
i get that jsonp response using this code, services.js

```js
var app=angular.module('F1FeederApp.services', []);
 app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {  
 $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'http://ergast.com/**'
  ]);
});
 app.factory('ergastAPIservice', function($http) {

    var ergastAPI = {};
    var urlFiltered = 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/driverStandings.json';
    ergastAPI.getDrivers = function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'JSONP', 
        url: urlFiltered
      });
    }
    
    return ergastAPI;
  });
```

now, i access it using the code below and gives me result on the 1st picture.

```js
angular.module('F1FeederApp.controllers', []).
  controller('driversController', function($scope, ergastAPIservice) {
    $scope.nameFilter = null;
    $scope.driversList = [];

    // //ergastAPIservice.getDrivers() ->> when i try this i get error this is not a function.
    //ergastAPIservice.getDrivers().success(function (response) {
        //Dig into the responde to get the relevant data
    //    $scope.driversList = response.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
    //});
    //code above doesnt work so i tried to access it or atleast show a value like
    // the code below
    console.log(ergastAPIservice.getDrivers());
    console.log(ergastAPIservice.getDrivers().MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings);
  });
```

now i get the 1st picture using console.log(*jsonp response*).
how can i get the list of drivers in that response?,
like: collectionVar = response.getDrivers();.
any link or same problem links would help thanks!

Comment: post your code instead of posting images

Comment: is it okay now guys? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this. This should work . You are getting a promise . Promises are handled like below. Learn more about [promise](http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/)

```
   app.controller("testController", function($scope,testService){
        testService.getDrivers ()
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.standingTable = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
                // handle valid reponse

            },
            function(error) {
                //handel error
            });


    }
```

Comment: someone down voted this answer Just wanted to know why :/

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks for Noman! i didnt know that i was getting a **angular promise** response at first. though i want to get the driver standing list. so i use this code.

```js
 $scope.driversList = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
```